# C# Preselected parameter values when calling a method

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

I am trying to make a method/function, which can work in two modes: bits or hex.
the user(programmer) should call this method while passing value and mode parameter.
I'd like to limit the mode parameter to a string of "bin" or "hex".
is it possible to generate a compiler error or warning (or pre-compiler error) when the user pass another unwanted value: such as "dec" ?

Example for acceptable parameters:

```
int decValueFromHex = convertToDec("111011","hex");
int decValueFromBin = convertToDec("111011","bin");
```

the below is not wanted, and need to generate an error somehow. (before final compilation)

```
int decValueFromDec = convertToDec("111011","dec");
int decValueFromMood = convertToDec("111011","hey");
```

Comment: That's what enums are for..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot apply rules on parameters like this. That's the entire point behind using an `enum` for example.

Try this:

```
enum Mode
{
    bin, hex
}

convertToDec("111011",Mode.hex);
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, but still user can pass invalid value

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: you mean for the first parameter?

Comment: ...an invalid value, such as an integer for the enum value, like `(Mode)-1`.

Comment: No, for second one. I'm talking about enum only

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, gunr2171: then you would be really stupid, huh ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes, it's stupid for you to do that, but it's possible. Say you are storing the enum value in a database as an int, you might move it back and get a non-enum value. This would also not cause a compiler warning if you tried `(Mode)-1` as well. So, there is no way to cause a warning, but this is the next best thing.

Comment: That why we use `Enum.TryParse`... :) Thanks for the explanation both.

Comment: Well, user could aswell call wrong method, or even worse.. use php syntax and wonder why his code's not compiling under VS. So much risk!

Comment: An assertion on the start of the method would do.

Comment: `Enum.TryParse`? Not sure I understand your comment. `Enum.TryParse` parses from string, but now we have enum. You need `Enum.IsDefined` but caveat is that `Enum.IsDefined` won't work with `Flags` :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: My bad. It was more referring to the general idea behind it.

Comment: so, you are saying that it is not possible to generate conditional compiler error, or any kind of custom error or warning... right ?

Comment: Not when using a plain string. Use `enum`.